# Only Serve Static Files From a Specific Directory via Code

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, asp.net-routing, iroutehandler

I am looking for a code based solution to only serving static files from a specified directory using ASP.NET routing rather than specify a `HttpHandler` in the `Web.config`.

For example:

I have the following partial directory layout

```
/
/public
/public/hello.txt
/public/css
/public/css/base.css
/readme.txt
```

If any files are requested from the `/public` directory they should be served as-is. If any other static files are requested for example `/readme.txt` it should be served as a `404`. The directory which allows static files to be served from should be easily specified as a string (`var publicDir = "public";`).

I am looking to do this with little to no configuration required in the `Web.config` file, and most of it configured in code.

Comment: What version of IIS you are using? windows 2008 + iis 7 or windows 2003  + iis 6?

Comment: I am looking for a solution that could be put into a class library, not something configured in IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it would be possible to achieve a solution using a class library. In **IIS 6** environment files with **.TXT or .JPG** extension  are served **without going through .NET** Framework. The only way is changing IIS configuration.

In **IIS 7** things are handled differently but I have no idea if it is possible to find a solution that works in all environments or not.

*I'll be pleased to hear what others say about this and correct me if i'm worng.*